# The stored procedure doesn't get created

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in MySql but I just get an error. Can somebody help me?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE colorAddOrEdit (
    in _id int,
    in _descripcion varchar(45)
    )
BEGIN
    If _id = 0 then
        insert into color (Descripcion_col)
        values (_descripcion);
        
        set _id = last_insert_id();
    else 
        update color 
        set 
        Descripcion_col = _descripcion
        where idColor_col = _id;
    end if;
    
    select _id = idColor_col;
end
```

The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `color` 
(
    `idColor_col` int NOT NULL,
    `Descripcion_col` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idColor_col`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

The error message:

> 08:52:19 CREATE PROCEDURE colorAddOrEdit ( in _id int, in _descripcion varchar(45) ) BEGIN If _id = 0 then insert into color (Descripcion_col) values (_descripcion) Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8 0.000 sec

Comment: *but it is just showing me an error message*; why not share the message here then?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76556923/edit) to add this important information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE colorAddOrEdit (
    IN _id INT,
    IN _descripcion VARCHAR(45)
)
BEGIN
    IF _id = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO color (Descripcion_col)
        VALUES (_descripcion);

        SET _id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    ELSE
        UPDATE color 
        SET Descripcion_col = _descripcion
        WHERE idColor_col = _id;
    END IF;

    SELECT _id AS idColor_col;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks u, but what was the matter in the mine?

Comment: @Dunknow no `DELIMITER` and also the keywords should be in upcase

Comment: Side note, check out MySQL Workbench, it can help you craft stored procedures and its free